# Use token but alert unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I use the express,passport,jwt to achieve restricted access using tokens.
The login interface generate token suceessfully,but when I use getKind interface whith rigth token,it alert me unauthorized.
main.js:

```
const passport = require('passport')
app.use(passport.initialize())
require('./config/passport')(passport)

const info = require('./routes/info')
app.use('/info', info)
```

passport.js:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
const keys = require('./key')
const {pool} = require('./key')

const opts = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    // the value of secretOrKey is "secret"
    secretOrKey: keys.secretOrKey
}

module.exports = passport => {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
            conn.query('select * from users where account = ?', [jwt_payload.account], (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err, false)
                }
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    return done(null, rows[0])
                } else {
                    return done(null, false)
                }
            })
            conn.release()
        })
    }))
}
```

login interface:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                code: 500,
                message: err.message
            })
        } else {
            let queryString = `select * from users where account='${req.body.account}'`
            conn.query(queryString, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        code: 500,
                        message: err.message
                    })
                } else {
                    if (result.length === 0) {
                        res.json({
                            code: 500,
                            message: "this user does not exist"
                        })
                    } else {
                        bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, result[0].password)
                            .then(isMatch => {
                                if (isMatch) {
                                    let rule = {
                                        account: result[0].account,
                                        password: result[0].password,
                                    }
                                    jwt.sign({payload: rule}, keys.secretOrKey, {expiresIn: 3600}, (err, token) => {
                                        if (err) {
                                            res.json({
                                                code: 500,
                                                message: err.message
                                            })
                                        } else {
                                            res.json({
                                                code: 200,
                                                message: "success",
                                                token: "Bearer " + token
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                } else {
                                    res.json({
                                        code: 500,
                                        message: "wrong password"
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

getKind interface:

```
router.get('/getKind', passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false}), (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                code: 500,
                message: err.message
            })
        } else {
            let queryString = `select distinct name from pipes`
            connection.query(queryString, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        code: 500,
                        message: err.message
                    })
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        code: 200,
                        message: "success",
                        data: result
                    })
                }
            })
            connection.release()
        }
    })
})
```

I use postman as client to test
Test result of login:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT0XW.png)
Test result of getKind:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmCx9.png)